# Are there any embedded Intel CPUs that can be soldered?

Tags: cpu, motherboard, intel

As known most of modern Intel CPU has contact pads instead of contact legs (pin). This makes it impossible to solder them onto the motherboard.

But are there any Intel CPUs which have contact legs (pin) and how to find them here http://ark.intel.com/ ?

Are there any embedded Intel CPUs that can be soldered?

Comment: 8051, 80186... Realistically, if you want to work by hand with moderately current x86 (where memory interface alone would kill your hopes) get a carrier module like the Edison thing.  There are some quite capable ARM MCU's in approachable QFP packages  though.

Comment: I recently bought a Avoton C2750 motherboard and I'm pretty sure that was soldered to the PCB. But it's a FCBGA1283 package not a hand soldering job if that's what you mean.

Comment: Why would you want to? Usually understanding the problem is half the answer.

Comment: @PeterJ Thank you! Yes, this is what I want. Do you know any else CPU-Sockets to which can be soldered CPU, or how to find them?

Comment: @jippie I need to create a shockproof system. Prerequisite is soldered processor.

Comment: Hah!  What makes you think soldering is "shock" proof? :).  Show me your shock proof soldered system and I will break it on my shaker table :). Also one reason a lot of faster processors are in sockets is because of thermal expansion.   Because of the thermal difference in the part vs the board the part expands more the motherboard which can easily break joints or crater pads.

Comment: @Alex: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intel_Atom_(CPU)

Comment: Please use correct terminology. Some processors are socketed (pins settle into a socket which locks). Some processors are leaded (meaning that they have pins, and I think this is what you are referring to) and some processors have some type of grid array (for example a ball-grid array or BGA). Both BGA and leaded processors are soldered onto the board. But BGA's are soldered using an oven process rather than wave or soldering iron.

Comment: BGA processors (and other components) can be underfilled with epoxy to improve mechanical properties. Usually shock is not the problem. The problem is bending of the PCB that causes failure. Thicker PCB's, or support frames which prevent PCB flex can help alot. But maybe you are making a control system for a rocket or race car or off-road vehicle or something. I have no experience with that. But I know that military equipment uses BGA packaged parts in many cases.

Comment: @mkeith Thank you! Do you mean, that BGA's are much more resistant to shocks then leaded processors? And about leaded processors - does meant any PGA-sockets FCPGA946(Socket G3)/FCPGA988(Socket G2)? I.e. leaded processors soldered using an wave or soldering iron, but BGA's (for example modern socket FCBGA1284 http://ark.intel.com/search/advanced?s=t&SocketsSupported=FCBGA1284&Embedded=true ) are soldered using an oven process, isn't it? And yes, we fill PCB/CPU with epoxy to improve mechanical properties.

Comment: I am an EE, not an ME. I assume that through-hole soldered parts are probably the most shock resistant. For SMT parts, the limiting factor is solder pad surface area and mass of the part. Failure would occur between copper pads and fiberglass of PCB. For many small BGA packages, the surface area to mass ratio seems favorable for high shock applications, but I am not an expert. Leaded parts can also be oven soldered. I believe most miniature electronics nowadays are oven soldered. I don't know much about sockets. I assume the weak point is socket to board joint.

Comment: My experience is in consumer electronics. The only shock testing we do is drop testing. I do not recall ever seeing a surface mount component of any type fail due to shock during a drop test. The failures occur when the housing deforms and mechanical items (E.g., LCD screen or battery) come into contact with PCB components. Inductors and chokes are the most likely to fail because they are big (more likely to come into contact with other components) and the material is somewhat brittle compared to plastic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course they can be soldered.  That's how they are mounted to the board during manufacturing.  The BGA (ball grid array) style of package you are referring to needs special equipment to solder, but absolutely it can be soldered.  That's how it's intended to be used.

Comment: Thank you! But is there any standard that describes how it should be done or what is the name of this special equipment to solder BGA (ball grid array) to find it?

Comment: @Alex: The datasheet should give information on the soldering temperature profile.  The equipment is just ordinary stuff for any volume assembler.  You need something that applies solder paste according to the stencil, a pick and place machine to accurately place the package onto the board, and a reflow oven to do the actual soldering.

Answer (score 1):

You want a leaded, possibly hand solderable cpu in a world of bga/lga cpus... Ball/Land Grid Array are leadless package types, which are soldered, using wave/reflow soldering. Modern x86 processors require hundred of connections, which leaded packages are not good at.

[image]

Comment: Minor nit, not wave/refow, just reflow.  Wave soldering is for thru hole and wouldn't work on a BGA package.